# How to update a database record and still keep the old values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to update a column by adding a new value alongside the old ones. So if column "fruits" has a value of "apples" and I run my query it should then have a value of "apples, oranges".

Right now when I do an update statement"

```
UPDATE tableName SET fruits='oranges' WHERE id=1;
```

It just overwrites apples with oranges. How can I get it to ADD the new value alongside the old separated by commas?

Comment: This really isn't a good schema.  You will probably problems querying these values down the road.  You should explain how you intend to use the data.  Depending what you want, a junction table may be a better solution.

Comment: Just learning sql and am building a basic blog so scalability isn't an issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableName SET fruits=CONCAT(fruits, ', oranges') WHERE id=1;
```

or:

```
UPDATE tableName SET fruits=CONCAT_WS(', ', fruits, 'oranges') WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: This won't do what he wants if `fruits` is empty.

Comment: True, but it sounds like there are existing values from the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
$reason_old = mysql_query("SELECT $col_name FROM `table` WHERE `unique_field` =$id");
$reason_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($reason_old);
$reason_box = $reason_all[$reason_fetch ];

$anyvariable= "UPDATE `$table_name` SET `$col_name ` = '$new_data , $reason_box' WHERE `unique_field` =$id";
$yes_good = mysql_query( $anyvariable, $conn );
```

Comment: You should add some kind of explanation. At first glance, it looks like this answer doesn't address the question at all.

Comment: Thanks for edit.. It's Just text design change not code.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend that you do is maintain *two* tables. The first table is like so.

```
TableFruit -> FruitID (PRIMARY KEY) + general fruit attributes
```

And then another table that maintains versions like so.

```
TableFruitVersions -> VersionID (PRIMARY KEY), FruitID (FOREIGN KEY), IsActive (BOOLEAN) + specific fruit attributes
```

You can add a single record the first time in both tables. The generic attributes of the fruit, or the context within which it appears, will go into the first table; and the specific fruit ("apple") will go into the next.

The next time you will add a specific fruit ("orange"), make the previous record in the second table false, and add the new record immediately thereafter.